# What's OnClickListner describe inside of View class in Android?

Tags: java, android

```
View.OnClickListener ob=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        };
```

In Above code OnClickListner a interface is implemented what's present inside View class. But I know implemented a interface code would be look like this->

```
View.OnClickListener ob=new View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        };
```

NOTE:I ONLY REMOVE THE BRACKETS BESIDE OF INTERFACE. BECAUSE BRACKETS ONLY TELLING ME ABOUT THE METHODS.BUT HERE onClickListner A INTERFACE.

Then why this interface implemented like a method?
Thank you..

Comment: https://medium.com/@manuaravindpta/lambda-expressions-in-android-97ee7648b0e8  Maybe lambda expressions is what you're looking for

Comment: Lambda expression only a new approach what's omitted old approach . But my confusion why onClickListener interface implemented like a method ?

Comment: It's called anonymous class, you can read more on it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes). Any so called functional interface (an interface with just one abstract method) can be expressed through a lambda. This is also true in your case, since `OnClickListener` only contains a method `onClick`.